# Call function few seconds after scroll form in C#

Tags: c#, function, winforms, scroll, timer

In form there is a timer and I want disable `timer.tick` when form scrolling and a few seconds after that again timer be enabled. How it is possible?
Best regards.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to stop the timer from ticking. You just need to prevent it from doing anything if someone has scrolled recently.

Write a timestamp each time a scroll occurs. You can do this by subscribing to the [Scroll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scroll?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event.

```
DateTime _lastScrollTime = DateTime.MinValue;

void MyControl_Scroll(object sender ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    _lastScrollTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Then in your timer event, check the timestamp to make sure nobody has scrolled recently before doing anything:

```
void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_lastScrollTime > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-2)) return;

    //Do timer stuff
}
```